# How do I append a "descendant" clause next to an xpath variable?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, descendant

This is what my code looks like

```
    public void someTest() {
      String x = "/html/body/div/div["
      String y = "]/a"
         for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            String links = x + i + y;
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(links)).click(); // This will iteratively go to the next link and click on it
         }
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve, however, is that once it clicks on the link, it should then look for descendant links and click on those as well. So is there a way of doing that? If I try something like the following, would that work?

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(links/descendant::a).click();
```

Comment: I don't get it. Post the part of your html maybe?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by descendant links? `<a>` tags don't normally have descendants. Perhaps you could post a representative part of the html, to show us the links you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fragile way of coding, altering the xpath as you go through the loop. Instead, I recommend using the findElements method and looping through the elements it returns, something like this:

```java
public void someTest() {
 xpath xpath_findlinks = "/html/body/div/div/a";
 xpath relative_xpath = "./..//a";
 for (WebElement eachlink : driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath_findlinks))) {
  eachlink.click();
  for (WebElement descendantlink : eachlink.FindElements(By.xpath(relative_xpath))) {
   descendantlink.click();
  }
 }
}
```

Note a crucial difference. The first time you call `findElements` it's on the *driver*, so it's looking through the entire html; but the second time, it's called as a method of *a particular element* (the current link), so you can use it to find elements *relative to that link* - e.g. to find descendants.

I recommend using this structure; however, without knowing your overall html it's hard to know what relative xpath to use. The one I have provided is just an example of what a relative xpath might look like, with the distinctive start of `./`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String x = "/html/body/div/div[";
  String y = "]//a"; // notice the double "//"
```

The `//` in the XPath should collate all the descendants of type `a`.

Comment: The problem is that the <a> becomes visible in another <div> after the parent link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You might need logic something like below

//For clicking on descendants of type `a` under `links`

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(links)).findElement(By.xpath("//a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is in Ruby. You can apply same logic using Java:

```
# get element of first div
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "/html/body/div") 

# collect all links elements in 'links' 
links = element.find_elements(:xpath, ".//div/a") variable

# iterate over links and click on each link
links.each do |link|
  link.click
end
```